# Jenkins - Writing variable to log file

Tags: jenkins

Running my jenkins pipeline I am able to have it output the commit message correctly using

```
gitnotes = sh ("git log -1 --pretty=%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s")
```

> 8c65c33   NAME HERE   Tue Nov 13 16:30:00 2018 -0500  Adjusted search/reset buttons' size in dashboard panel

However I now want to store those commit notes to a log file, but even when I use an echo it comes back as null.

```
echo "${gitnotes}"
```

I might be losing my mind, but how would I go about writing the above notes to a log file? I'm having a super bad day apparently as this is something I am just not looking at correctly.

Comment: Try setting returnStdout: true. Eg: gitnotes = sh script: "git log -1 --pretty=%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" , returnStdout: true

Comment: I knew it, as soon as I read your answer I realized what I had forgotten. This worked flawlessly, thank you!

Comment: Please upvote the answer

Comment: Upvoted, but account is too new/unused for it to count it said. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry, Select the checkbox which states that you accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `returnStdout: true`

Eg: `gitnotes = sh script: "git log -1 --pretty=%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" , returnStdout: true`